# Grab tag and the attribute of XML file using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

please i need some help with Python.
i have the folowwing result XML.

```
bloc_elements = soup.find_all('bloc')
```

**RESULT =>**

```
print(bloc_elements)

<Bloc>
<a>data_a</a>
<b>data_b</b>
<c>data_c</c>
<d>data_d</d>
</Bloc>
```

am trying to get this result :

```
List into CSV file : 
a       b       c        d  
data_a  data_b  data_c   data_d
```

this is what i have done:

```
elements_list = []
for element in bloc_elements:
    elements_list.append(element.get_text())

print(elements_list)
am getting infortunatly this result:

data_a
data_b
data_c
data_d
```

Problems:

- I lost the tag (label of the line )
- the results are in vertical not horizontally

thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

A simple `list` and `dict` comprehension does it.  Clearly you can use `to_csv()` to create a CSV from the data frame.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Bloc>
<a>data_a</a>
<b>data_b</b>
<c>data_c</c>
<d>data_d</d>
</Bloc>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, "lxml")
df = pd.DataFrame([{ee.name: ee.text for ee in e.find_all(recursive=False)} for e in soup.find_all("bloc")  ])
```

### output

```
      a       b       c       d
 data_a  data_b  data_c  data_d
```

Comment: Hello Rob, Thank you so much i ve tried it on my code and really it works...
have more things to learn in Python...thank you again. 

just for my knowledge.
{ee.name: ee.text for ee in e.find_all(recursive=False)}
this part of code is done to grab the labels ? what is the recursive function?
Thank you so much

Comment: it's not recursive,  only want direct descendants https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-recursive-argument

Comment: Okay , i got it . thnk you again Rob

Comment: Hello Rob, please :) can you help me with this issue ?? thank you , its in the same file.

 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65748393/beautifulsoup-parsing-xml-to-table